# PyQt5 TextEdit Widget Changeing font colour of input text

Tags: css, python-3.x, pyqt5

i cant find out how to change the font color in pyqt5. heres the code i have for a `textedit` widget

```
self.sendmessage_textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.sendmessage_textedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 351, 401))
        self.sendmessage_textedit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);\n"
"border-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);")
```

the default text colour is black when text is entered but haveing a dark window black isnt the best option. can i just edit the code and add a line in in

```
self.sendmessage_textedit.setStyleSheet
```

similar to this??

```
font-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

`font-color` doesnt seem to work.

or can i edit it somthing like this

```
font: 11pt \"Times New Roman\"white"\;
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct property for font-color is `color`. Other font-properties you can set with `font`.

```
self.sendmessage_textedit.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);'
                                        'border-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);'
                                        'color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'
                                        'font: bold italic 20pt "Times New Roman";'
                                        )
```

see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)